# SignInAsync vs AuthenticateAsync

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, access-token

I finally got my login-method with JWT Token Authentication working.

Here I'm calling

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    ClaimsPrincipalFactory.CreatePrincipal(claims),
    authProps);
```

I also called

```
await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

In the example I read that I only need the `SignInAsync`. 
So I tested it and removed `AuthenticateAsync`. But still, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` returns `true`.

Is it okay to remove the `AuthenticateAsync`? Or do I still need it? Why does it exist?
The doc-string of `AuthenticateAsync` only says *Extension method for authenticate*

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here's a recap between all the various methods coming from the Authentification framework (for ASP.NET Core 2.0), in the order in which they're called in a typical auth flow.

**ChallengeAsync**

This will instruct your browser on where to go to be authenticated. For example:

- Cookies will redirect you to your own login page (e.g. `/Account/Login`)
- Azure AD will redirect you to the Microsoft login page
- etc..

**AuthenticateAsync**

This step handles whatever information comes from the authentication page (where you were redirected to by the Challenge step), and uses it to create a `ClaimsPrincipal` instance that identify the logged in user.

That `ClaimsPrincipal` is then assigned to `HttpContext.User`.

**SignInAsync**

This step takes the `ClaimsPrincipal` built from the previous step, and persists it. The most common way is of course the cookies.

Note that based on the source code in https://github.com/aspnet/Security/, it seems to be the only way to persist the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

**SignOutAsync**

This is the reverse step of the `SignIn` step. It instructs the middleware to delete any persisted data.

- Cookies will delete the stored cookie
- Azure AD will redirect you to their Microsoft logout page
- etc..

---

So to answer your question, if you already have a `ClaimsPrincipal`, calling `AuthenticateAsync` is not necessary.

In fact, it's a bit strange that you have a `ClaimsPrincipal` before calling `AuthentificateAsync` :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Not sure if I did something wrong, the `ClaimsPrincipal` is built in my TokenProviderMiddleware, as soon as the identity is confirmed...

Comment: `This step takes the ClaimsPrincipal built from the previous step, and persists it. The most common way is of course the cookies.` - what is the other way (besides cookies) that is supported by SignInAsync?

Comment: Are you able to help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76215954/what-to-put-for-the-scheme-in-authenticationhttpcontextextensions-authenticateas ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question recently and figured it out.

**AuthenticateAsync**

The `AuthenticateAsync()` method of the Authentication Handlers is responsible for constructing the `ClaimsPrincipal` from the Request and return it to the Authentication Middleware. The Authentication middleware then sets the `HttpContext.User` Property with the `ClaimsPrincipal`.([reference](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/authentication-in-asp-net-core/#authentication-scheme))

From my understanding, `AuthenticateAsync()` method is used internally by asp.net core, we normally don't need to call it as we can access `HttpContext.User` Property to get the `ClaimsPrincipal`. But you can call this method in your code to get the `AuthenticateResult` if you want(but not necessary).

**SignInAsync**

This is used when you first authenticate the user after they log in, so you build `ClaimsPrincipal` in your code and call `SignInAsync` to persist the claims like write to cookie.