# What is the difference between PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials versus HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync in Identity Server

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I have implemented SSO with Windows account in Identity Server by calling `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync` in the ExternalController, as was the default code that was already present in the Identity Server MVC code ([see this code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs)). This all works fine.

In some other code I found another approach, and I was wondering why they did it like that. Basically what they do is validate credentials in the `AccountController` like:

```
using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
{
    return principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
}
```

...and if validation succeeds, they do:

```
await httpContext.SignInAsync(username, username, new AuthenticationProperties());
```

So my question is: what is the difference between the two approaches and which one is the recommended approach for authenticating a user against Windows?

Comment: this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818980/signinasync-vs-authenticateasync

Comment: Thanks! So basically AuthenticateAsync is the way to go, because it handles external authentication completely, and so potential future external authentication providers will also be handled by default.

Comment: You´re correct!