# What to put for the scheme in AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.AuthenticateAsync()

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, .net-6.0, openid-connect, okta-api

I'm using OIDC with Identity Server 4 which is authenticating with Okta.

I'm calling `var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Identity.External");` in a callback method.

I chose `Identity.External` as the scheme because I noticed that was the name of the cookie in the request to the callback method:
[image]

However, I realised I could rename this cookie using this code in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
    services.ConfigureExternalCookie(config =>
    {                
        config.Cookie.Name = "test12";
    });
```

[image]

But after renaming the cookie, the call to `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Identity.External")` still works, so it appears that the scheme name has nothing to do with this cookie name.

**How do we know what string value to put in there?**

**Is there a list of acceptable values somewhere?**

Here's my `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // "Cookies"
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenIdConnect", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "oktaUrlHere";
    options.ClientId = "clientIdHere";
    options.ClientSecret = "clientSecretHere";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.Scope.Add("groups");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Events = new CustomOpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        ...
    };
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried prepending the scheme with "1" just to see what would happen:

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("1Identity.External");
```

It returned this error which contains a list of registered schemes:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme '1Identity.External'.

The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, idsrv, idsrv.external, Cookies, oidc. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("1Identity.External",...)?
```

**Are these schemes all registered by default?**

**Is this documented anywhere?**

**UPDATE:**

I put a breakpoint in the following code to view the values for the properties on `options`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

I can see the default value for `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` is `Identity.Application`, and the default value for `DefaultSignInScheme` is `Identity.External`.

Since `options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme` has a value, `options.DefaultScheme` (`"Cookies"`) will not be used.

According to [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationoptions.defaultauthenticatescheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-authenticationoptions-defaultauthenticatescheme), `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` is:

> used as the default scheme by AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext, String).

If that's the case, why does the scheme passed to `AuthenticateAsync()` need to be the value for `DefaultSignInScheme` (`"Identity.External"`) and not `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` (`"Identity.Application"`)?

**UPDATE:**

In this Duende [example](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/ui/login/external/), they use:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("AAD", "Employee Login", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

        // other options omitted
    });
```

and authenticate using:

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

which also goes against what the Microsoft documentation says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the name of the cookie is unrelated to what you are trying to do.

In your Client configuration, you typically have something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(opt =>
{
   ...

}).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
   ...
});
```

What you put inside this method

```
HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Identity.External")
```

Is the name of the scheme.

But, typically, when you use OpenIDConnect, you want to challenge the user via the OpenIDConnect handler, so if what you are trying to achieve is to ask the user to login, then you should use something like this:

```
HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

To, summarize:

you can name the handlers whatever you like, and then you register what handler to handle which event.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "MyCookieScheme";       //Do use the cookie handler for everyhthing except Challenge
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyOIDCScheme";
}).AddCookie("MyCookieScheme", opt =>
{
}).AddOpenIdConnect("MyOIDCScheme",options =>
{
});
```

Then later in the code when you want to ask the user to login.

```
//Please use the handler with the MyOIDCScheme name to challenge the user 
HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("MyOIDCScheme");
```

About the question about those specific names, the names are registered internally by IdentityServer, for example, see the log here:
https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Support/issues/477

IT says in the log output:

```
[13:35:16 Information] Duende.IdentityServer.Startup
Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer

[13:35:16 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Startup
Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication

[13:35:16 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Startup
Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in

[13:35:16 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Startup
Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out

[13:35:16 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Startup
Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge

[13:35:16 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Startup
Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
```

Comment: I'm using asking the user to log in by redirecting them via `return Challenge(props, provider);` which seems to be working fine. Is that the same as using `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`?

Comment: I'm using `"Cookies"` as the `DefaultScheme`, not `"Identity.External"`. If the value passed to `AuthenticateAsync()` needs to match what I have in `ConfigureServices()`, which is `"Cookies"`, then how does the `AuthenticateAsync()` call still succeed?
I've updated my question with my Startup.cs code.

Comment: I just debugged `services.AddAuthentication()` and can see `options.DefaultSignInScheme` is `Identity.External`, but `options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme` is `Identity.Application`. Now I'm really confused because it would appear that I should use `AuthenticateAsync("Identity.Application")` which results in `result.Succeeded = false` in the callback.

Comment: return Challenge(props, provider) or ChallengeAsync is the same thing, asking the user to authenticate.

Comment: In the client application, the Authenticate function is managed by the cookie handler and its job is to convert the incoming cookie (if found and valid) into a ClainsPrincipal user, that'all. You typically don't call Authenticate in your code.

Comment: But I might have read your question wrong, what I wrote is about the client application talking to IdentityServer. For Federated, see this page https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/ui/login/external/

Comment: In your answer you say `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Identity.External")` but how did you know to use `"Identity.External"`? Does this have to be set in `Startup.cs`? If so, where?

Comment: Its just a custom name of an authentication handler,  similar to you set AAD to be the name of the  handler in this code snippet: .AddOpenIdConnect("AAD"....,) somewhere you added handler with then name Identity.External.

Comment: But there's also `idsrv`, `idsrv.external`, `Identity.External`, `OpenIdConnect` etc, how did you know to use `Identity.External` and not the others?